# Multiprocessing Listener-Client two-way connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, communication

I am trying to make two Python processes communicate: One script (`Listener.py`) should run in the background in an endless loop. The other script (`Client.py`) should be executed whenever needed.
Each time, `Client.py` is executed, it is supposed to send some information in a Python `dict()`. `Listener.py` should read these information, use it as input to do some things and send back a result. `Client.py` should wait for the response and save it or print it.

So far, I have found examples of how to send data from one process to another. Based on what I found online, I assumed the following should be working:

**Listener.py**

```
import time
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# Settings
address = ("localhost", 6000)
listener = Listener(address, authkey = b"Passwort")

def do_something(img_path):
    
    time.sleep(1)
    
    return "I slept for 1 sec.."

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# Run and listen
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        connection = listener.accept()
        try:
            conn_in = connection.recv()
            print(conn_in)
            if conn_in is not None:
                done_something = do_something()
                connection.send({"how long I slept" : done_something,
                                 "you told me" : conn_in["tale"]})
        except:
            print("Something unexpected happened...")
        
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

**Client.py**

```
import datetime
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
address = ("localhost", 6000)

with Client(address, authkey = b"Passwort") as connection:
    connection.send(
        {"tale" : "Once upon a time..."}
        )
    
    response = connection.recv()
    print(response)
```

However, it is not.

I start the `Listener.py` script first and then run the `Client.py`. Unfortunately, something causes the `Listener.py` to crash. It does receive the information sent by `Client.py` but it does not respond.

Currently, I cannot wrap my head around how this should work and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-listeners-clients) on the functions I think I need is rather brief. Maybe there are even better Python packages or different functions to do the job?

Comment: You should look at the exception that is raised in the listener: You are trying `done_something = do_something()` but `do_something` requires an argument (`img_path`).

Comment: The documentation you linked says "Usually message passing between processes is done using queues or by using Connection objects returned by Pipe()." Why not use that?

Comment: @AKX I read about queues but if I recall correctly, there were some conditions that my project didn't meet. I thought in that case I would have to start one of the scripts as a thread or subprocess from a main Python script. I might well be wrong on that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Timus for pointing out the error in my MWE. Fixing this and the issue mentioned below this answer, the code is now working.

The below version of `Listener.py` should work now...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection = listener.accept()
    conn_in = connection.recv()
    
    while True:
        try:
            meantime = time.time()
            
            if conn_in is not None:
                for d in conn_in:
                    stuff = do_something("test")
                    
                    connection.send({"image" : stuff})
            connection.close()
            connection = listener.accept()
            conn_in = connection.recv()
        except:
            continue
        
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: *So far, it works well for the first request but ends up unresponsive after that.* - `connection = listener.accept()` is inside the loop, expecting a brand new incoming connection at every iteration. You may want to put it in front of the loop instead.

Comment: @tevemadar THanks, I think I figured it out now... I close the connection and re-open it after each request.